# Запятая после части предложения, которая начинается с "При..."

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, пояснительные, обстоятельственный-оборот

> При отгрузке товара в понедельник 1 февраля(,) крайним днем оплаты будет считаться 15 февраля. При отгрузке 15 февраля — 2 марта.

Нужна ли запятая перед словом *крайним*, и если нужна, то почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае такие части, а именно обстоятельства, выраженные существительными с предлогами (в том числе ***при***), могут выделяться запятыми. Но это зависит от многих факторов и часто является факультативным (см: [Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114,2)).

Если бы в предложении не было дня недели или даты, например: *"При отгрузке товара 1 февраля крайним днем оплаты будет считаться 15 февраля"*, то запятая не требовалась бы.

Но в исходном предложении нужны **две запятые**, ставящиеся на другом основании – выделении даты в качестве [пояснительной конструкции](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119).

*При отгрузке товара в понедельник, **1 февраля,** крайним днем оплаты будет считаться 15 февраля.*

> **Вопрос № 294989**
> Здравствуйте. Нужна запятая в скобках? В понедельник, вторник и среду(,) 23-25 октября, ночью мороз.
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Указанная запятая нужна, так как слова *23–25 октября* выступают в роли пояснительного члена предложения.

> **Вопрос № 304869**
> Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая: В понедельник, 9 марта (,) состоялась встреча...
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Указанная запятая нужна.

> **Вопрос № 272270**
> Нужно ли обособлять дату запятыми? Во вторник(,) 3 марта(,) в школе откроют музей.
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
> Да, запятые ставятся: *Во вторник, 3 марта, в школе откроют музей.*

Ответы на сайте "Грамота.ру": [**1**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4), [**2**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA).

Comment: Александр, добрый день. Текст сейчас выглядит так: *"Товар должен быть оплачен в течение 10 рабочих дней. При отгрузке товара в понедельник 1 марта крайним днём оплаты будет 16 марта."* День недели (понедельник), таким образом, не является более важной частью предложения, чем сама дата (1 марта).  Они важны в абсолютно равной степени, - одно без другого смысла иметь не будет. С учетом сказанного, вы уверены что запятые следует ставить именно так, как у вас сейчас? Выши знания русского языка сомнению не подвергаю, просто уточняю.

Comment: @jsx97 Да, понедельник не является более важной частью, они равноправны. Пояснение – это выражение того же самого другими словами. *В понедельник, то есть / а именно 1 марта*. Считаю, что запятые нужны.

Comment: Могу добавить следующее. Нет никакой необходимости для уточнения. А если нет, то в деловых бумагах это слишком свободный стиль.  Подучается, что мы противопоставляем день недели (понедельник) и дату (16 марта).

Comment: @jsx97, добрый вечер. Интересно, а почему сначала было 15 число, а сейчас 16-е? День отгрузки не входит в эти 10 дней для оплаты?

Comment: @Sharon, тогда и к 16-му надо добавить вторник.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец День отгрузки, действительно, не входит (у нас в фирме). Но дело не в этом. Если присмотреться, там весь нюанс в том, что между 1 и 15 февраля нерабочих дней только четыре - две субботы и два воскресенья. Если рассматривать тот же диапазон, но в марте, к нерабочим дням добавляется 8 марта.

Comment: Форма записи выбирается автором текста. Ему  виднее, какая запись ему подходит. Но не стоит сюда вмешивать правила и регулировать что-либо. Правила допускают любой вариант (с уточнением и без уточнения). Ну мне так кажется.

Comment: @Sharon Почему не стоит? Как раз в деловых бумагах, которые бывают настолько "сложносочиненными", и нужно максимально придерживаться правил. Вы всё-таки свитаете это уточнением, а не пояснением? Или здесь это не столь важно?

Comment: @Sharon Я поменял следующим образом: "При отгрузке товара 1 марта, выпадающим на понедельник, крайним днём оплаты будет 16 марта." Это инструкция "для своих" и напоминалка для меня лично. Стиль там возможен, поэтому, как более сухой, так и менее, а вот ошибок и сомнений в пунктуации хотелось бы избежать. (У меня на этот счет небольшое ОКР.)

Comment: @jsx97  Кажется, это отличный выход из ситуации.

Comment: @jsx97 А почему "выпадающ**им**"?

Comment: @oleedd Да, речь о дате, а не о марте, поэтому, пожалуй, правильнее будет "выпадающ**ей**". Звучит, правда, по причине пропуска слова "дата", очень плохо `:(` Выбор мужского грамматического рода можно оправдать тем, что, мол, речь идет не про **дату**, а про **день**.

Comment: Уважаемые друзья! Разве мы пишем по образцам из Грамоты.ру? Нет, мы пишем «по идее». Вам кажется, что вы подобрали точно такой же вариант? Но каждое предложение индивидуально, и для него нужно собственное решение. Разве не этому учит нас Розенталь? На примеры мы только ориентируемся, а вот правила  в данном случае позволяют выбирать между неоднородными и уточняющими отношениями в обозначении даты и дня недели. Нужно работать точно в рамках ПРАВИЛ, но при этом чувствовать себя свободным. Только нужный смысл — и вы.

Comment: Чтобы сказать совсем просто. Правила предлагают ВЫБОР для обозначения координат (дата и день недели): однородные или уточняющие отношения. (При уточнении скорее день недели будет обособлен.) Это информация от РЕДАКТОРА. Автор, и только он, может сделать правильный выбор ПО СМЫСЛУ, как он его понимает. И тогда это будет ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ автора, а не редактора. Это я к тому, кто и за что отвечает.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Без запятых дата является определением ("какой понедельник?"; их же много). А с запятыми не пояснение, а уточнение ("какой именно понедельник?"). Пояснение, если так: *В следующий понедельник, [то есть] 1 марта.*

Comment: @oleedd  Определения тоже могут обособляться. А вообще, мне уже всё равно, что это. Уточнения, пояснения очень часто переплетаются в смыслах и в головах. Что я нашел, на то и опираюсь.

Comment: @jsx97 Нет, это неверно, поэтому и не звучит. Надо: *выпадающего* (речь о числе, по грамматике согласуется со словом "первый", мужской род). Есть разговорный вариант с творительным: *при отгрузке первым числом, выпадающим на понедельник*. Может, поэтому хочется так написать. Лучше всего — написать "понедельник" в скобках, это очень в духе делового стиля.

Comment: Я тоже за скобки, тем более что это "для своих", а сомнительной пунктуации хочется избежать.

Comment: @oleedd Здесь я не согласна. У нас есть три возможности записать временной  обстоятельственный оборот: обозначить информацию сразу и полностью (без уточнений) или с уточнением любой координаты.  Размышления о том, что дата и день недели взаимно связаны, настолько очевидны,  что не стоит их приводить. В любом случае это выбор автора текста, не надо решать его задачи за него.   Неблагодарное это  занятие.

Comment: @Sharon С чем вы не согласны? 1) Говорю о том, что можно без запятых. 2) Говорю о том, что скобки лучше, чем запятые, так как деловой стиль.

Comment: Со вторым не согласна. Это выбор автора текста, не надо решать его задачи за него. От таких занятий одни неприятности. У каждого из трех лиц (писателя, редактора и читателя) свои цели и задачи. Какие – подумайте сами.

Comment: @Sharon Это особенность делового стиля, там принято уточнять в скобках. Насчёт выбора автора: всегда есть лучший вариант, но у нас не всегда есть достаточно информации, чтобы определить, как лучше, но обычно достаточно.

Comment: Ваше дело – обозначить выбор по правилам,  и это все. А у автора достаточно информации, чтобы по смыслу сделать выбор из предложенных ему вариантов. Это же очевидно – каждому свое. Если же вам неочевидно, то вас же могут обвинить в неправильном решении (или вы сами себя будете обвинять). А оно вам надо?  Насчет делового стиля согласна относительно запятых, а ваши скобки там тоже ни к чему. Деловые люди в календарике дату посмотрят.

Comment: @Sharon Часто трудно определить, какой вариант лучше подходит. Поэтому постоянно говорю: указывайте, какой вариант лучше и почему. Часто один вариант хороший, а второй заметно хуже (это не про этот случай, а в общем), а спрашивающие будут считать, что 50/50.

Comment: Это да, но лучший вариант был у автора текста, там он записывает оборот без запятых и скобок. Александр добавил вариант, и вот что из этого получилось: много шума, ночные разговоры и головная боль для всех участников.  А причина понятна: люди стали решать не свои задачи. Вот вам и ваши варианты... На этом и закончим.

Comment: @Sharon Это вам к Александру. Моё "лучше всего" изначально имело смысл "лучше всего так, если уже обособляем" (и опять мне казалось, что поймут).

Comment: А я читала, как там у вас было изначально? Я только утром кое-что прочитала. И давайте на этом уж закончим,  ага?

Comment: @Sharon У меня изначально так и было. Но имелось в виду то, как лучше написать, если разделить. Там это обсуждалось...

Answer (score 4):

***При отгрузке товара в понедельник 1 февраля** / крайним днем оплаты будет считаться 15 февраля. При отгрузке 15 февраля — 2 марта.*

**В деловых сообщениях** обстоятельственный оборот в начале предложения обычно не обособляется, хотя произносительная пауза делается. По правилам (в общем случае) обособление **факультативное**.

Если поставить **запятую** (обозначить грамматическую паузу), то оборот будет подчеркнут. Это уже выбор автора.

**ИЗ КОММЕНТАРИЕВ** (обсуждение ответов, запись 29.05.2023 в 9-00)

**Форма записи** выбирается автором текста. Ему виднее, какая запись ему подходит. Но не стоит сюда вмешивать правила и регулировать что-либо. Правила допускают любой вариант (**с уточнением и без уточнения**).

Могу добавить следующее. Нет никакой необходимости для уточнения. А если нет, то в деловых бумагах это слишком свободный стиль. Подучается, что мы **противопоставляем** день недели (понедельник) и дату (16 марта).

Уважаемые друзья! Разве мы пишем **по образцам из Грамоты.ру**? Нет, мы пишем «по идее». Вам кажется, что вы подобрали точно такой же вариант? Но каждое предложение **индивидуально,** и для него нужно собственное решение. Разве не этому учит нас **Розенталь?**

На примеры мы только **ориентируемся**, а вот правила в данном случае позволяют выбирать **между неоднородными и уточняющими** отношениями в обозначении даты и дня недели. Нужно работать точно в рамках **ПРАВИЛ**, но при этом чувствовать себя свободным. **Только нужный смысл — и вы.**

Чтобы сказать совсем **ПРОСТО**. Правила предлагают **ВЫБОР** для обозначения координат (дата и день недели): неоднородные или уточняющие отношения. (При уточнении скорее **день недели будет обособлен.**) Это информация **ОТ РЕДАКТОРА.**

Автор, и только он, может сделать правильный выбор **ПО СМЫСЛУ**, как он его понимает. И тогда это будет **ОТВЕТСТВЕННОСТЬЮ АВТОРА**, а не редактора. Это я к тому, кто и за что отвечает.

Розенталь: [Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)

Comment: Что за редактор? А вы себя к ним не относите? А почему же вы здесь грамматику не указываете? Дружеская подсказка. Вот где это нужно. Когда однородные, запятая ставится, между прочим, так что не тот термин. Знаете, как здесь? Или сдаётесь и мне написать?

Comment: Когда мы отвечаем на вопросы, то становимся как бы редакторами. Олид, какие однородные, где  вы их увидели? В понедельник 1 февраля – неоднородные координаты, в понедельник, 1 февраля – уточняющие, весь оборот – обособленное или необособленное обстоятельство. И знаете, я, пожалуй, с вами еще немного подружу, а то меня совсем тут камнями закидают :) А это стихи (между прочим,  одного из наших бывших участников форума):  «Как страшно быть одним из многих, Идти дорогой  большинства,  И не  искать своей дороги, И жить тем, чем толпа жива». Да только этим «ищущим» тоже бывает неуютно.

Comment: У вас в ответе увидел: *Правила предлагают ВЫБОР для обозначения координат (дата и день недели): однородные или уточняющие отношения.* А у меня другая грамматика, поинтересней (будет под другим ответом). Да, это правильно (про стих), не не надо делать совсем уж ерунду и этим отличаться.

Comment: Я не найду, может, раньше так было. Да мне уж без разницы, все равно меня мало кто понимает. Ведь по существу ответа и комментариев ничего не сказано и ничего не скажут. А тогда зачем мне говорить... Классные стихи, правда? Понимаете, человек может делать что-то очень нужное и важное, а люди считают, что ерундой занимается. С другой стороны, Герострат сжег храм, чтобы прославиться.  Уж он-то точно не был "одним из многих".  Но... «И средь богов тысячеоких, И средь давно УПАВШИХ В ГРЕХ Как страшно быть одним из многих,  А не единственным из всех».

Comment: Как это не найдёте? Я же процитировал. В том же абзаце, где мнение редактора. Но у вас же два плюса, чего вы грустите? Да, стих хороший и полезный. *человек может делать что-то очень нужное и важное, а люди считают, что ерундой занимается* — это другое дело, а бывает, что полная ерунда (бред). Вот Jim Korbett считает ерундой то, что он не понимает. Но так нельзя. Я же считаю ерундой то, что не является верным.

Comment: Точно, спасибо, исправила.  Два плюса к 130 К мало что добавят,  да и их могут отозвать.  Участники же голосуют против моего МНЕНИЯ (это уже огорчает немного).   Вы говорите: "Я же считаю ерундой то, что не является верным".  Во-первых, по большому счету истина всегда относительна;  во-вторых,  почему вы думаете, что именно вы знаете хотя бы эту относительную истину. Я, к примеру, никогда так не считаю про себя. Только если уж применяю совершенно очевидные правила.

Comment: Потому что крайне маловероятно ошибиться в том, что для тебя очень просто. А если не просто, то не стану ничего утверждать. Вот, вы тоже о таком говорите ("совершенно очевидные правила"). Нет, истина не относительна (либо верно, либо нет), относительны добро и зло.

Comment: Ладно, Олид, спасибо за внимание. А о добре и зле пусть философы рассуждают...